# how to construct a vector from quaternion

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Messages like Pose or PoseStamped have a orientation which is a quaternion. I would like to construct a vector3 of length 1 facing in the direction of the orientation from the quaternion. Is there a helper function in tf to acomplish this?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36517/how-to-construct-a-vector-from-quaternion/) by [blejzzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2431/blejzzz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2012-06-14

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When using the TF library, you can use the method tf::quatRotate to rotate your vector by the rotation represented by the quaternion. E.g. the following code rotates your vector by 180 degrees around the x axis:

```
tf::Quaternion rotation(1, 0, 0, 0);
tf::Vector3 vector(0, 1, 0);
tf::Vector3 rotated_vector = tf::quatRotate(rotation, vector);
```

Don't forget to include `tf/tf.h`.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [blejzzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2431/blejzzz/) on 2012-06-14**:
so for instance if i set a goal in rviz and use your code (and replace the values of rotation with the goal orientation) and construct a new point like so: goal.position + rotatedVector; it will result in a point 1 meter forward in the goal direction/orientation?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-06-14**:
Yes. I think so. Alternatively, you can convert your goal to a  tf::Stamped<tf::Pose> and multiply it with another tf::Pose with origin 1 0 0 and rotation 0 0 0 1. Same maths but less code. Also see for convertion functions: http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/tf/html/c++/transform__datatypes_8h.html

**Comment by [blejzzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2431/blejzzz/) on 2012-06-15**:
it works. thanks alot! Just one note in electric quatRotate isnt in tf namespace it is in btQuaternion.h.